# the connectionstring porperty has not been initialized

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

So im trying to fill my textboxes based on my combobox which is also linked in my sql server.

Im having this error everytime I select an item in my ComboBox.

> The connectionstring property has not been initialized

```
    Private Sub CBuname_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CBuname.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "Select * From CoAdminData where Username='" & CBuname.Text & "'"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If Reader.HasRows() Then
            While Reader.Read
                txtSID.Text = Reader("StudentID")
                txtFirstname.Text = Reader("Firstname")
                txtLastname.Text = Reader("Lastname")
            End While
        End If
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Well, you haven't shown how you initialize the connection. There's something wrong with it's connection.-string. It's probably not assigned.

Comment: The error message says that the `ConnectionString` property has not been initialized. What's not clear about that? Did you actually look at the `ConnectionString` property when the exception was thrown to see what it is? Do some investigation when an exception is thrown.  VS includes a debugger for a reason.  If you don't know how to debug, [learn how](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @TimSchmelter little bobby tables strikes again!

Comment: `con` has a `ConnectionString` property. You need to set it, or it won't know how to connect with your database.

Comment: i have the sqlconnection in my Public Class and i think its working becuase the link between combobox and database is working

Comment: Your combobox probably has its own connection object or setting, which is unrelated to what you want to do here with `con`.

Comment: i tried using a natural textbox and inserting the code in a button but same error occured

Comment: Don't put the "resolution" into the question.  You can always post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give a complete example and template that you can use / modify. I have commented everything you need to get going.
Rather than declaring the con in a public class, try just having it open and close with each method. You can publicly declare the constr elsewhere, which could save you some writing.
Hth

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient 

Private Sub Template_SQL_Reader()
    'Obviously rename SQL with you server, DATABASE with the DB, USERNAME and PASSWORD with your creds too
    Dim constr As String = "Server=SQL;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;uid=USERNAME;Pwd='Password'"
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)

    'Carefull not to include query string that could allow
    'SQL injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
    Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM TABLE" '<<< Ok - No SQL Injection avaliable
    'Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FirstName='" & textbox1.text & "'" <<< BAD IDEA SQL Injection Possible !!!!!!
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(qry, con)

    'Open connection
    con.Open()
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While rdr.Read
        'If there are no rows - then nothing will happen, as .read = false
        'Do your reading...
    End While

    'Dispose command
    cmd.Dispose()
    'close connection
    con.Close()
End Sub
```